# Spark action stuck with EOFException

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to execute an action with Spark with gets stuck. The corresponding executor throws following exception:

```
 2019-03-06 11:18:16 ERROR Inbox:91 - Ignoring error
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskDescription$$anonfun$decode$1.apply(TaskDescription.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskDescription$$anonfun$decode$1.apply(TaskDescription.scala:130)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:160)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskDescription$.decode(TaskDescription.scala:130)
at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcV$sp(Inbox.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher$MessageLoop.run(Dispatcher.scala:221)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My environment is a standalone Spark cluster on Docker with Zeppelin as Spark driver. The connection to the cluster is working fine.

My Spark action is a simple output of a database read like:

```
spark.read.jdbc(jdbcString, "table", props).show()
```

I can print the schema of the table, so there shouldn't be a problem with the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your environment JAVA, Python, Pysaprk must be same in MASTER and WORKER  and path, version same too

Answer (score 1):

Our driver machine had a different version of Java compared to spark standalone cluster. When we tried with another machine with the same java version, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in one of folder available on S3. Data was stored as Parquet with Snappy compression. When I changed it to ORC with Snappy compression, it worked like charm.